# Не подключается PostgresJDBC Driver через maven

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, maven

Я начал подключать Postrgres JDBS драйвер через maven вот от [сюда](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4):

И ничего не подключилось Вот мой `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>siteParser</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</project>
```

Во вкладке Maven Projects в IDEA он не отображается в

```
siteParser
    Lifecycle
    Plugins
    Dependencies
        org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2
        junit:junit:4.12
        //И его нет(((((должен быть postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4
```

И нажатие Reimport Maven Projects не помогает.

Ну и при попытке:

```
Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432",
            "postgres",
            "1");

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
```

Помогите пожалуйста может быть кто-то сталкивался с таким? На другом модуле в этом же проекте все тоже самое работает. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven здесь не причем. Перед первым обращением к драйверу JDBC надо загрузить класс драйвера, обычно это делается вызовом:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

[RTFM](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/load.html)

Comment: вылетает java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver К тому же в соседнем модуле он подключен так что это не первый ну по краиней мере для проекта

Comment: Так вы явно вызываете `Class.forName()`?

Comment: Да как там написано просто взял и выполнил `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` а как надо?

Comment: Если при вызове `Class.forName()` возникает исключение, значит в `CLASSPATH` нет драйвера, стало быть проблема в `maven` - или смотрит не в ту репу или еще что-то. И прочтите в конце-то концов мануал! А то вроде человек вы разумный судя по репе, а задаете какие-то десткие вопросы

Comment: так и я говорю что в maven, хотя <dependency> указал, раньше когда я так делал все работало((( в соседнем модуле так же подключено и работает а тут не хочет((

Comment: причем тут соседний модуль! "Читайте по губам" - перед первым вызовом надо вставить в код `Class.forName()` и посмотрите где он валится.

Comment: в `java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass` и валится а где же ему еще то валиться если `maven` библиотеку не подгрузил. Нет класса с таким именем.

Comment: спасибо конечно за помощь не надо волноваться проблема просто в том что `<dependencies>` не там закрыл вот он и не подгружал.

Comment: Да, тоже увидел